# Laravel migrations package

Tags: php, laravel, migration

Are Laravel migrations completely custom or does it use a library underneath it all like [doctrine/migrations](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/migrations.html)?

I would like to reuse the package in one of my non-Laravel projects, but I feel Doctrine package may be an overkill.

I've tried to check `composer.json` of Laravel vendor directly, but I found nothing related to migrations apart from some test files. Has anyone tried reusing just a part of Laravel?

Comment: this should help https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Migrations.html

Comment: This is just list of methods and properties. Doesn't make it usable externally

Comment: you can get the illuminate database class

Comment: i use it quite often with Slim